# How to print address of all the dymanically allocated bytes

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

First of all i am not sure whether my question is correct.

Here's the question.

```
char* ch = new char[20]
```

Now i want to know the address of each of the 20 bytes allocated.

I want to do something like

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    cout<<ch++;
```

I am getting blank characters on doing this. Isn't this the correct way to do?
Can't i print address of all 20 bytes?

My aim :- I will allocate initially 20 bytes of memory for character type. Now i want to write one character at a time in each memory location. How to do this?

Comment: You just need to now the address of the first byte. All the other addresses follow that address in steps of 1-byte per... well, byte...

Comment: @barakmanos thanks for your reply. I agree to your comment. But i specifically want to know if this is possible to know the address of any random byte suppose 10 can't i have something like &(ch+10) as we do *(ch+10) to get data.

Comment: Your goal as described at the bottom of the question implies that you probably want to use a `string` instead. If you insist on using a `char` array, then you can set each `char` as simple as (for example) `ch[5] = 'f'`. If you want to be able to use it as a string, then you should set the last one to zero (`char[19] = 0`, or if the length of the string is less than 19 bytes, then `char[len] = 0` for whatever `len` it is). In order to print the address of `ch` you can do something like `cout<<hex<<(int)ch`.

Comment: If you pass a character pointer to `cout<<`, it treats it as a pointer to a null-terminated string and prints the characters in that string. To print the pointer as a number, you need to cast to `void*`. `cout << (void*)ch`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    const unsigned int COUNT = 20 ;
    char *ch = new char [COUNT] ;

```
for (unsigned int ii = 0 ; ii < COUNT ; ++ ii)
{
   void *tmp = &ch [ii] ;
   cout << tmp << endl ;
}
```